# Rails 5.2.2.1 ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, updates

I updated my company's application from Rails 5.2.1 to Rails 5.2.2.1. Upon running our test suite post-update, I am encountering issues with validating uniqueness within the scope of a model, specifically, when appending a model to the ActiveRecord relation of another model. For example, in our application, if I were to do `@person.cars << @car`, we would run a uniqueness validation (`validates :car_id, uniqueness: { scope: :group_id }`. Even in a scenario where `@person.cars` was originally empty, our post-update branch is throwing validation errors on this uniqueness check. These test cases work on our master branch (pre-update), but not on our update branch (post-update). There have been no other changes made to the application besides updating Rails from 5.2.1 to 5.2.2.1. I am wondering if anyone knows of any existing bugs or issues in relation to Rails 5.2.2.1 uniqueness validations that may be causing this. I have looked through the changelogs of both Rails and ActiveRecord, as well as a few other dependencies that were updated, but I have been unable to find anything.

Comment: Did ActiveRecord make any changes to your database tables? Like add a validation requirement to person.cars? See any db:migrate logs/commands during the update?

Comment: No changes to the database at all, nor any commands that were run.

Comment: Posting the errors would help.

Comment: The error message being outputted is generated ourselves, but it's an ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid error. `ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Form can't be used because one already exists for this vendor`.

Comment: Which other dependencies changed in your `Gemfile.lock`?

Comment: can you post the full backtrace errors? without the code and/or at least more details, we can't help

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is an issue with a change made in Rail's `ActiveRecord::Associations` which used to remove duplicates in version 5.2.1, when appending to an ActiveRecord association. This never threw a RecordInvalid exception, as the duplicate would be removed before hand. In 5.2.2.1, it looks like that has been removed, and any duplicates appending to an association will no longer be preemptively deleted (most likely to mimic Ruby += functionality). I had to change all your uses of += to a relation to |= to ensure duplicates were no longer being appended on.

Sorry for no being able to post any code or stack traces. The stack trace was very application specific and wouldn't have been helpful at all, and the code is proprietary. Appreciate the help!

Comment: Did you mean https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/33954 ?

Comment: Yes I believe this was the same issue. Thank you for posting the link!